# python call all functions with name patterns or other signature

Tags: python, object

I'm writing a feature generation class that can be extendable. For example in the following example any method that starts with `generate` is a feature generation method:

```
class FeatureGenerator:
    def __init__(self): 
        self.generate_a()
        self.generate_b()
    def method_a(self): pass
    def generate_a(self): do stuffs
    def generate_b(self): do stuffs
```

I want to execute all methods with `generate` prefix within init. However, I don't want to add it manually every time I write a new method. One solution could be writing a decorator that will add it to a list and then execute all elements in the list within init. But I am not sure that's a good idea. Is there any pythonic way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [`dir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir) of the instance:

```
class FeatureGenerator:
    def __init__(self): 
        for name in dir(self):
            attr = getattr(self, name)
            if callable(attr) and name.startswith("generate"):
                attr()
    def method_a(self): pass
    def generate_a(self): print("gen a")
    def generate_b(self): print("gen b")
```

Comment: I would manually walk through the MRO.. `dir` is not meant to be used this way. The docs evens state "supplied primarily as a convenience for use at an interactive prompt, it tries to supply an interesting set of names more than it tries to supply a rigorously or consistently defined set of names". So just `for klass in type(self).mro(): for attr, name in vars(klass).items():`...

Comment: maybe even skip `object`: `for klass in type(self).mro()[:-1]`

Comment: You probably meant `for name, attr in vars(...)`

Comment: Thanks! I experimented with both the answer and both works well for my purpose. To make juanpa.arivillaga's answer complete: `for klass in type(self).mro()[:-1]: for name, attr in vars(klass).items(): if name.startswith('generate'): attr(self)`

Comment: ^ Beware that using vars would require special handling for classmethod and staticmethod (dir does not)